# Where is $(z^2+4)^{-1}\text{Log}(z+2i)$ Analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

> The question states: Where is the function $(z^2+4)^{-1}\text{Log}(z+2i)$ analytic (where Log denotes the principal complex logarithm).

My attempt:

First note that if $z=\pm 2i$, then $(z^2+4)^{-1}$ is not analytic.

Also, we know that Log$(g(z))$ is not analytic if $g(z)\in(-\infty,0]$. So  $\text{Log}(z+2i)$ is not analytic iff $$z+2i\in(-\infty,0].$$
But I'm unsure of how to simplify this expression. Do we equate real and imaginary components to determine a condition for $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&z+2i\in(-\infty,0] \\
&\implies\Re(z+2i)\in(-\infty,0] \text{ and } \Im(z+2i)=0 \\
&\implies\Re(z)\in(-\infty,0] \text{ and } \Im(z)=-2\\
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, $\frac{\operatorname{Log}(z+2i)}{z^2+4}$ is analytic on
$$\mathbb C\setminus\{2i\}\setminus\{z~:~ \Re(z)\in(-\infty,0] , \Im(z)=-2\} $$

Comment: The answer given is the complement of the set $\{2i\}\cup\{x-2i:x\leq 0\}$. I do not understand the second bracket.

Comment: @Bell Try to draw the set on a complex plane. Then you will see my answer is equivalent to yours.

Comment: Shouldn't $\Im(z)=-2$? If $\Im(z)=-2i\implies i(-2i)+2i=2+2i$. Don't we want the imaginary components to cancel?

Comment: @Bell Sorry! That’s a silly mistake.